# Checking multiple conditions in while statements for python

Tags: python

```
while MenuChoice != '1' or '2' or '3':
    MenuChoice = input('What would you like to do? (Type a number):')
```

This is the code I have at the moment, however, when the code is executed, the `MenuChoice` user input is repeated no matter what character is entered (this includes 1, 2, and 3)

How can I make it so that the program checks if the user's input for `MenuChoice` (prior to this section to code) was '1', '2', or '3' and if not, repeat the `MenuChoice` input?

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Your logic is wrong.  Use `while MenuChoice != '1' or MenuChoice != '1'..`

Comment: try `while !(MenuChoice in  ['1','2','3']):`

Comment: or `while MenuChoice not in ['1','2','3']:`

Comment: set is a good choice for membership test: `MenuChoice not in {'1','2','3'}`

Comment: Thanks for the answers, PRMoureu, your one seems to work.